# How to validate cheque number and MICR No in c#

Tags: c#

I am working on certian app, where user has to input bank Cheque number MICR number. I am looking to alert user when he is not inputting it in proper way. Is there any regex for Cheque and MICR validation. Is there any way to achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if there are any specific but base on my research Cheque Number and MICR Code only contains numbers and are only 6 characters long and 9 characters long, respectively. I'm not sure if that is the standard around the world but I think you could start there.

Answer (score 0):

Below regex can be applied.

```
        //Make sure the first digit does not start with zero
        string pattern = @"^[1-9][0-9]{8}$"; //if always 9 digits are required
        //pattern = @"^[1-9][0-9]{5,8}$"; //if always 6-9 digits are required
        string inputValue = "560240004";
        if (Regex.IsMatch(inputValue, pattern))
        {
            Debug.Print($"Input text {inputValue} matches.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Print($"Input text {inputValue} does not match.");
        }
```